# Machine Learning: Repetitive Pattern recognition regardless of amplitude and frequency

Tags: time-series, lstm

I am trying to scope out an approach to learn to identify repetitive human body activity based on collected motion data and would like some advice on some challenges I identified. I determined a set of data, the approach, and a set of potential challenges using cosine waveforms as an analogy before I start on the actual work.

#### Data:

Self generate the data by creating a long series of cosine waves of varying frequencies and amplitudes.

#### Machine Learning approach:

- Sequence input with X dimensions
- LSTM with Y hidden units
- Z fully connected layer
- Softmax
- Classification Output with cross entropy

#### Challenge:

One particular challenge I will face is that the network is likely to only learn to classify cosine waveforms based on the frequencies and amplitudes that appears in the training set.

How should I modify my approach to make it less sensitive to the frequency and amplitude and more on the signature cosine waveform that we see?

Comment: what is signature? you make your training data representative, by drawing train and test randomly from the (simulated) population